# Django multiple files in one field

Tags: python, django, sqlite, file-management, filefield

I am trying to make a database using sqlite3 with a field for multiple files so that i can have a file list on mt model info page. For example if the model is student and he needs to store an unspecified number of homework files and needs to be able to add, view, edit and delete them. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need multiple files in one field, you need a separate Files table with a foreign key to the student.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a **homeworkfile model**. In that model add a **file_upload field**.

And then relate student table to homeworkfile model using **one-to-many relationship**.

```
class homeworkfile(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/%Y/%m/%d/')
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea, is there anywhere I can find documentation for referencing and editing  these files?